# What did this user do to warrant a 1 year suspension?

Tags: discussion

I found [this user](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/16993/vietnhi-phuvan) had 1 rep yet there are [plenty of upvotes](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/21562/583) on this answer. After going through his profile, apparently he has been sent to the [penalty box](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for a year.

I've going through his answers and they are all high quality, and the answers he's supplied before the penalty was enacted have multiple upvotes. This user seems to be a great contributor to The Workplace, the antithesis of "troll account". I'm going to guess that whatever his transgression, it was removed for moderation reasons - especially if it was egregious enough for a *one year suspension*.

So what did this user do, or, more generally, what type of behavior warrants a one-year suspension? (Specifics need not be mentioned if it infringes upon the privacy of those involved in the transgression.)

Comment: consider that you haven't seen if user had deleted answers / comments. This means some part of the picture is not visible to regular users. One interesting example worth looking at is [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/46970/168)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For privacy reasons, moderators and Stack Exchange employees do not reveal reasons for suspensions.  If the *user* brings it up (elsewhere or after) that's different, but it's not for us to say.  We don't like suspending people; we aren't going to then pour salt in the wound by telling the world more than necessary.

Besides, it would be pretty rude of us to talk about a suspended user when he couldn't respond, don't you think?

Two *general* things:

- You probably aren't seeing everything.  If there was a problem with somebody's posts or comments, those were removed as part of dealing with the problem.  If there was a problem involving voting, you wouldn't be in a position to know (even mods don't know *much*; investigating voting irregularities requires a CM).
- Suspension periods escalate with repetition; it is very very rare for a *first* suspension to be for a year.

It always makes me sad when a user with many good contributions gets suspended.  Suspension is not something we do lightly, but when we do it the same rules apply to everybody, whether they have 100 rep or 100k rep.